# Node.JS - Looping through arrays within an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, puppeteer

im a bit confused now. I want on puppeteer to start 5 browsers in the same time and give each of the browser his own socks5.

```js
let socks = [array of socks]
```

Now i want to loop the array socks within every new browser i will start, but im not really sure how i can do it.

here is my code so far:

```js
let socks = fs.readFileSync("socks.txt", "utf8").split("\r\n");

async function start() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await brower.newPage();
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  start(i, launchOption);
  wait(1000);
}

function wait(ms) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var end = start;
  while (end < start + ms) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

HOW can i loop through the socks array for each instance? Its not clear for me...thanks for any help!

Comment: you really should not block the main thread like that. Better `const wait = delay => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));` and then, inside the loop, `await start(...)` `await wait(1000);` although I'm not sure wether you'd still need to wait if you await `start`

Answer (score 1):

you can pass is as argument to evaluate function

```
await page.evaluate((socks) => {
  console.log(socks); 
  socks.forEach((sock) => {
    /* your logic here */
  })
}, socks);
```